# Consultar por coincidencias en una matriz mongoose

Tags: nodejs, regex, mongodb, mongoose

tengo varios registros en mi bd:

```
{
"etiquetas": [
    "Comestible",
    "Infusion",
    "Dolor de cabeza"
],
"nombre_comun": "Menta"
}
```

**Usando mongoose.**

**Quiero hacer una consulta a mi bd y que solo me traiga mis objetos(fichas) que en sus etiquetas tengan "comestible"**, este  es un valor es introducido por el usuario, lo intente hacer de esta manera pero no me dio resultado:

```
const fichas = await Ficha.find({ etiquetas: { $regex : coindicidencia, $options: 'i' } });
```

Igual de esta manera :

```
const fichas = await Ficha.find({ etiquetas: { "$regex" : coindicidencia, "$options": 'i' } });
```

**Las dos formas me dan este error:**

```
(node:8485) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoServerError: $regex has to be a string
```

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar cómo estás declarando la variable `coindicidencia`?. En todo caso, tal vez no necesites el operador `$regex`, un simple `Ficha.find({ etiquetas: coincidencia});` podría dar resultado. Saludos

Comment: si era eso, estaba mal nombrado:(

Answer (score 0):

Fue un error muy novato, estaba mal escrito el nombre de el parametro en la ruta, por eso no buscaba coincidencias.